# Ordering a list by size using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

My code right now:

```
 public GameObject[] Farms;

 Farms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Farm").OrderBy(x => Vector2.Distance(this.transform.position, x.transform.position))
                                                  .ThenBy(x => x.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<FoodSpawn>().FoodList.Count)
                                                  .ToArray();
```

What I have:
So my scene has a rectangle floor.
A cube left, a cube right and a AI (player) in the middle.
Each cube is filled with 7 pieces of food (childs of the main cube).
The cubes have a tag `Farm`.
The list `FoodList` is a `GameObject` list that in the script that is attached to each Cube, that list contains each piece of food in the cube.

What I want to achieve:
The player needs to decide which cube filled with food he wants to go.
But he needs to take the distance to the cube and the amount of food in consideration.
So the player needs to order the list in such a way that the closest farm & the farm with the most food is the 1st element of the list.

Right now the list does get properly ordered by distance, so the closest cube is the first element but it skips the `.ThenBy` line (or im doing something wrong).

Comment: What is your input? What is your output? What did you expect instead? Please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: Your code orders by distance first. But ONLY when distances are equal, it will sort by food count.

Comment: Ill look into that Johan, thanks didnt know that.

Comment: you will have to combine distance and food amount into one metric, which is a task we would need more details to help you with

Comment: Please provide an example, on what the current data is, what you expect and what are you getting, else its not possible to guess the issue

Comment: it's just "too much" for a game engine.  while it's admirable to be a Linq mechanic, it's just not the place for it.  make it all tremendously simpler.  ADD SOME DATA FIELDS to your objects (your cubes or whatever).  proceed in sweeps.  for example, first quickly set on each object the distance to the player (or whatever).  go through it in sweeps like that and get a result.  you can't chop up big Linq calls between frames (in a coroutine) so it's really not the solution.  in any commercial setting you just can't have code that "tight" or "tricky" in a unity project, it's not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As @Johan mentioned in comments that `ThenBy`only works if there is a tie between two objects in `OrderBy` clause. In your case, as you want to consider both parameters, ***distance*** AND ***number of food items***. You need to do a bit of maths here. Depending on priority which each parameter have you can use something like:

```
OrderBy(x => (distanceForX * priorityOfDistance) + (foodCountForX * priorityOfFoodCount))
```

And instead of

```
transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<FoodSpawn>();
```

you can use

```
GetComponentInParent<FoodSpawn>();
```

Comment: Could you explain abit more what you mean with the priority part?  
I assume you mean with `distanceForX` the distance between the cube and the player.  
And with `foodCountForX` the amount of food each list has?

Comment: Yes. you got me right. calculate the distance and foodcount same way. I provided psuedocode.

Comment: Sorry i still don't really understand what you mean with `priorityOfDistance` and `priorityOfFoodCount`

Comment: These numbers may represent priority of each factor in sorting. For example, if priority of food count is double than distance than you can use priorityOfFoodCount = 2 and priorityOfDistance = 1.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to first make it sort the list of Farms on distance.
I also gave the Farms a bool that checks if the farm contains food or not.
Then the player decides to go the closest farm that has the `HasFood` bool on true.

```
Farms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Farm").OrderBy(x => (Vector2.Distance(this.transform.position, x.transform.position)))
                                                 .ToArray();

ClosestFarm = Farms.First(x => x.GetComponentInParent<FoodSpawn>().HasFood == true);
```